# Is one view that handles two sibling models a good idea?

Tags: python, object-oriented, mvc, django

I am using Django multi-table inheritance: `Video` and `Image` are models derived from `Media`. There are two views: `video_list` and `image_list`, which are just proxies to `media_list`. `media_list` returns images or videos (based on input parameter `model`) for a certain object, which can be of type `Event`, `Member`, or `Crag`. The view alters its rendering behaviour based on input parameter `mode`, which can be of value "edit" or "view".

The problem is that I need to ask whether the input parameter `model` contains `Video` or `Image` in `media_list` so that I can do the right thing. Similar condition is also in helper method `media_edit_list` that is called from the view.

I don't particularly like it but the only alternative I can think of is to have separate (but almost the same) logic for `video_list` and `image_list` and then probably also separate helper methods for videos and images: `video_edit_list`, `image_edit_list`, `video_view_list`, `image_view_list`. So four functions instead of just two. That I like even less because the video functions would be very similar to the respective image functions. What do you recommend?

[Here](http://pastebin.com/07t4bdza) is extract of relevant parts. I'll also paste the code here:

#### URLs

```
url(r'^media/images/(?P<rel_model_tag>(event|member|crag))/(?P<rel_object_id>\d+)/(?P<action>(view|edit))/$', views.image_list, name='image-list')
url(r'^media/videos/(?P<rel_model_tag>(event|member|crag))/(?P<rel_object_id>\d+)/(?P<action>(view|edit))/$', views.video_list, name='video-list')
```

#### Views

```
def image_list(request, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, mode):
    return media_list(request, Image, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, mode)


def video_list(request, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, mode):
    return media_list(request, Video, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, mode)


def media_list(request, model, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, mode):
    rel_model = tag_to_model(rel_model_tag)
    rel_object = get_object_or_404(rel_model, pk=rel_object_id)

    if model == Image:
        star_media = rel_object.star_image
    else:
        star_media = rel_object.star_video

    media_list = model.get_object_media(rel_object).filter(~Q(id=star_media.id)).order_by('date_added')

    context = {
        'media_list': media_list,
        'star_media': star_media,
    }

    if mode == 'edit':
        return media_edit_list(request, model, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, context)

    return media_view_list(request, model, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, context)


def media_view_list(request, model, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, context):
    if request.is_ajax():
        context['base_template'] = 'boxes/base-lite.html'
    return render(request, 'media/list-items.html', context)


def media_edit_list(request, model, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, context):
    if model == Image:
        get_media_edit_record = get_image_edit_record
    else:
        get_media_edit_record = get_video_edit_record

    media_list = [get_media_edit_record(media, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id) for media in context['media_list']]

    if context['star_media']:
        star_media = get_media_edit_record(context['star_media'], rel_model_tag, rel_object_id)
    else:
        star_media = None

    json = simplejson.dumps({
        'star_media': star_media,
        'media_list': media_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(json, content_type=json_response_mimetype(request))


def get_image_edit_record(image, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id):
    record = {
        'url': image.image.url,
        'name': image.title or image.filename,
        'type': mimetypes.guess_type(image.image.path)[0] or 'image/png',
        'thumbnailUrl': image.thumbnail_2.url,
        'size': image.image.size,
        'id': image.id,
        'media_id': image.media_ptr.id,
        'starUrl':reverse('image-star', kwargs={'image_id': image.id, 'rel_model_tag': rel_model_tag, 'rel_object_id': rel_object_id}),
    }
    return record


def get_video_edit_record(video, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id):
    record = {
        'url': video.embed_url,
        'name': video.title or video.url,
        'type': None,
        'thumbnailUrl': video.thumbnail_2.url,
        'size': None,
        'id': video.id,
        'media_id': video.media_ptr.id,
        'starUrl': reverse('video-star', kwargs={'video_id': video.id, 'rel_model_tag': rel_model_tag, 'rel_object_id': rel_object_id}),
    }
    return record
```

#### Models

```
class Media(models.Model, WebModel):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=128, default='', db_index=True, blank=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    crag = models.ForeignKey(Crag, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    tagged_in_members = models.ManyToManyField(Member, blank=True, related_name='tagged_in_media_set')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='added_images')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField('date added', auto_now_add=True, null=True, default=None, editable=False)

    @classmethod
    def get_object_media(cls, rel_object):
        filter_params = {}

        if rel_object.__class__ == Event:
            filter_params['event'] = rel_object.id
        elif rel_object.__class__ == Member:
            filter_params['member'] = rel_object.id
        elif rel_object.__class__ == Crag:
            filter_params['crag'] = rel_object.id

        return cls.objects.filter(**filter_params).all()



class Image(Media):
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='uploads',
                                processors=[ResizeToFit(width=1024, height=1024, upscale=False)],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 75})
    thumbnail_1 = ImageSpecField(source='image',
                                processors=[SmartResize(width=178, height=134)],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 75})
    thumbnail_2 = ImageSpecField(source='image',
                                #processors=[SmartResize(width=256, height=192)],
                                processors=[ResizeToFit(height=164)],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 75})


class Video(Media):
    url = models.URLField('url', max_length=256, default='')
    embed_url = models.URLField('embed url', max_length=256, default='', blank=True)
    author = models.CharField('author', max_length=64, default='', blank=True)
    thumbnail = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='uploads',
                                processors=[ResizeToFit(width=1024, height=1024, upscale=False)],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 75}, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    thumbnail_1 = ImageSpecField(source='thumbnail',
                                processors=[SmartResize(width=178, height=134)],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 75})
    thumbnail_2 = ImageSpecField(source='thumbnail',
                                #processors=[SmartResize(width=256, height=192)],
                                processors=[ResizeToFit(height=164)],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 75})

  class Crag(models.Model, WebModel):
      name = models.CharField('name', max_length=64, default='', db_index=True)
      normalized_name = models.CharField('normalized name', max_length=64, default='', editable=False)
      type = models.IntegerField('crag type', null=True, default=None, choices=crag_types)
      description = models.TextField('description', default='', blank=True)
      country = models.ForeignKey('country', null=True, default=None) #TODO: make this not null when db enables it
      latitude = models.FloatField('latitude', null=True, default=None)
      longitude = models.FloatField('longitude', null=True, default=None)
      location_index = FixedCharField('location index', length=24, default='', editable=False, db_index=True) # handled by db, used for marker clustering
      added_by = models.ForeignKey('member', null=True, default=None)
      #route_count = models.IntegerField('route count', null=True, default=None, editable=False)
      date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True, null=True, default=None, editable=False)
      last_modified = models.DateTimeField('last modified', auto_now=True, null=True, default=None, editable=False)
      star_image = models.ForeignKey('Image', null=True, default=None, related_name='star_crags', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
      star_video = models.ForeignKey('Video', null=True, default=None, related_name='star_crags', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since posting this question I have rewritten the code completely. However, to solve this particular issue, one could rewrite:

```
if model == Image:
    star_media = rel_object.star_image
else:
    star_media = rel_object.star_video
```

to

```
star_media = model.get_star_media(rel_object)
```

`get_star_media` would be class method of `Video` and `Image` models (defined as stub in `Media`) that returns star media of the respective type. Shifting the problem to model layer and using polymorfism is the key. Otherwise, the approach of using one view is alright.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid the "is Image or Video" checks in `media_list`, by passing in some extra arguments, for example in `image_list`:

```
def image_list(request, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, mode):
    get_star_media = lambda rel_object: rel_object.star_image
    return media_list(request, Image, get_star_media, get_image_edit_record, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, mode)
```

I added two extra arguments there, the `get_star_media` function to extract `rel_object.star_image` and `get_image_edit_record`. Similarly for `video_list`:

```
def video_list(request, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, mode):
    get_star_media = lambda rel_object: rel_object.star_video
    return media_list(request, Video, get_star_media, get_video_edit_record, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, mode)
```

This way you could rewrite the `media_list` and `media_edit_list` methods without the Image/Video checks like this:

```
def media_list(request, model, get_star_media, get_media_edit_record, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, mode):
    rel_model = tag_to_model(rel_model_tag)
    rel_object = get_object_or_404(rel_model, pk=rel_object_id)
    star_media = get_star_media(rel_object)

    media_list = model.get_object_media(rel_object).filter(~Q(id=star_media.id)).order_by('date_added')

    context = {
        'media_list': media_list,
        'star_media': star_media,
    }

    if mode == 'edit':
        return media_edit_list(request, get_media_edit_record, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, context)

    return media_view_list(request, model, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, context)

def media_edit_list(request, get_media_edit_record, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, context):
    media_list = [get_media_edit_record(media, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id) for media in context['media_list']]

    if context['star_media']:
        star_media = get_media_edit_record(context['star_media'], rel_model_tag, rel_object_id)
    else:
        star_media = None

    json = simplejson.dumps({
        'star_media': star_media,
        'media_list': media_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(json, content_type=json_response_mimetype(request))
```

---

You're passing many arguments to `media_view_list` that are not used:

```
def media_view_list(request, model, rel_model_tag, rel_object_id, context):
    if request.is_ajax():
        context['base_template'] = 'boxes/base-lite.html'
    return render(request, 'media/list-items.html', context)
```

You could simplify by dropping `model`, `rel_model_tag` and `rel_object_id` from the argument list.